# Dynamically add icon name with Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to dynamically add icon names to my Ionic 2 app, the reason for this is that I have a list of attributes on my model, which are dynamic, the model returns the icon name to the ionic 2 application.

This is the response I'm getting from my API.

```
{
  "type": "searchresult",
  "count": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "type": "room",
      "url": "/api/room/1",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "type": "attribute",
          "url": "/api/room/1/attribute/1",
          "name": "attribute1",
          "icon": "people",
          "valueType": "bool",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "type": "attribute",
          "url": "/api/room/1/attribute/3",
          "name": "attribute2",
          "icon": "desktop",
          "valueType": "bool",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "type": "attribute",
          "url": "/api/room/1/attribute/4",
          "name": "attribute3",
          "icon": "md-videocam",
          "valueType": "bool",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "type": "attribute",
          "url": "/api/room/1/attribute/5",
          "name": "attribute4",
          "icon": "icon-chair",
          "valueType": "int",
          "value": "200"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This is what I have in the Ionic2 app at the moment.

```
<ion-row no-padding *ngFor="let att of room.attributes">
    <ion-col width-20 no-padding text-center>
        <ion-icon name="att.icon"</ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens here is that when you use `name="att.icon"` you're just passing the **plain word** `att.icon` to your `name` *attribute*, but in this case `att` is an object and `icon` is a key of this `object`.

That said, you want to use property binding like `[name]` instead of `name`:

```
<ion-icon [name]="att.icon"></ion-icon>
```

Compiler now will evaluate the value of the expression and assigns the value to the `name`.

Check the demo:

<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tIBZs1CM1SrfFbJmk4Pa?p=preview)</kbd>

---

**Other questions:**

- [Angular 2 : HTML property binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581255/angular-2-html-property-binding)
- [Property binding vs attribute interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112904/angularjs2-property-binding-vs-attribute-interpolation#answer-39114303)

Comment: I was thinking the same.. does it pic the icon like `src` attribute? or does it only pic from the imported icon directory?

Comment: can you please explain the difference between name and [name]?

Answer (score 3):

Another way which I use is :

```
<ion-icon name={{att.icon}}></ion-icon>
```

Same thing works for `src` of `img` tag also

```
<img src={{att.image}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like `<ion-icon name="{{att.icon}}"></ion-icon>`.

Answer (score 0):

When data has come from ngFor I've had to use this before :

[attr.name]="ngForItem.name"

(using your code) :

```
<ion-row no-padding *ngFor="let att of room.attributes">
    <ion-col width-20 no-padding text-center>
        <ion-icon [attr.name]="att.icon"</ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```