# angular class replacement binding interpretation

Tags: angular

Angular provides a replacement binding syntax as follows :

```
[class]="badCurly"
```

Does it mean the class is set to string "badCurly" or the class is set to value resolved from badCurly property belonging to component ?

This is different from attribute binding as it doesn't use the . syntax. Its specifically about class binding.

The accepted answer solved the query and answers that this will be resolved from component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property binding vs attribute interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112904/property-binding-vs-attribute-interpolation)

Comment: @HarunYılmaz this addresses different issue.

Comment: No it doesn't. And also you may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321526/difference-between-ngclass-vs-class-binding

Comment: @HarunYılmaz it is unfortunate that you dont understand the question. cant help..

Comment: I completely understand the question. It is attribute/property binding of Angular and is not different for `class`. Besides, Angular provides extra `ngClass`, `class.xxx` binding syntax. Therefore, the two links I provided should work well for you.

Comment: My question is not about ngClass, class.xxx  as you are thinking. It is about just [class]. Anways , Nithin P.H has understood it and answered it. Dont worry. Thanks for downvoting as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[class]="badCurly"`
In your ts file what ever the value of the object **badCurly** is that will be the value of the class

[here is an example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvhjvm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)